# How to switch to next page(call another class) from ImageButton that Extend Fragment android programming

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, imagebutton, android-imagebutton

This is the PagesFragment file.

```
public class PagesFragment extends Fragment {

    public PagesFragment(){

    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pages, container, false);


        ImageButton s1 = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.speakers_1);
        s1.setOnClickListener(listener);

        ImageButton s2 = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.speakers_2);
        s2.setOnClickListener(listener2);

        ImageButton s3 = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.speakers_3);
        s3.setOnClickListener(listener3);

        return rootView;

    }

    ImageButton.OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    };

    public void speak_1 (View theButton)
    {

        Intent i = new Intent(this.getActivity(),speaker1.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

This is the xml file

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/speakers_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtLabel"
    android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:onClick="speak_1"
    android:src="@drawable/speakers_1" />
```

How can I call speak_1? I also want to switch to another xml when the ImageButton is clicked. Thank you.

Comment: The xml and java code should be all in "code style"

Comment: code style what? i was newbie for programming

Answer (score 1):

Passing different listener for each ImageButton separately is quite strange. Try to do it this way:

```
public class PagesFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    public PagesFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pages, container, false);

            ImageButton s1 = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.speakers_1);
            s1.setOnClickListener(this);

            ImageButton s2 = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.speakers_2);
            s2.setOnClickListener(this);

            ImageButton s3 = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.speakers_3);
            s3.setOnClickListener(this);

            return rootView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // here you can handle your ImageButton clicks

        int id = v.getId();
        if (id == R.id.speakers_1) {
            speak_1();
        } else if (id == R.id.speakers_2) {
            speak_2();
        } // etc...

    }

    public void speak_1() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this.getActivity(),speaker1.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void speak_2() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this.getActivity(),speaker2.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

It's also good practice to make first letter of a class name capital, it's a standard naming convention (Speaker1 instead of speaker1).

Comment: i doesn't work. the logcat say FATAL ERROR: main
java.lang.ClassCastException: info.androidhive.slidingmenu.PagesFragment cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener

Comment: Did you properly implement OnClickListener interface for PagesFragment class?

Comment: i haven't. how to properly implement OnClickListener interface for my PagesFragment class?

Comment: So that is the problem. :) You have to define your class like in the example above: public class PagesFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener { // ...}. Then you must implement methods of your OnClickListener. If you use Android Studio, put your cursor on the OnClickListener, then use Alt + Enter to implement onClick method (it is the method that is overriden in the example above). That should solve your problem.

Comment: oh, thank u. if i use eclipse where should i put that method on my script?

Answer (score 0):

To call a method just use  `speak_1(arg0)` inside `onClick()`

**Example**

```
ImageButton.OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
    speak_1(arg0);
    }
};
```

Comment: It doesn't work. the Logcat says 
FATAL ERROR : main
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
public class PagesFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    public PagesFragment(){

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pages, container, false);


        ImageButton s1 = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.speakers_1);
        s1.setOnClickListener(this);

        ImageButton s2 = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.speakers_2);
        s2.setOnClickListener(this);

        ImageButton s3 = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.speakers_3);
        s3.setOnClickListener(this);

        return rootView;

    }

    public void speak_1(View theButton)
    {

        Intent i = new Intent(this.getActivity(),speaker1.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view instance of ImageButton)
            speak_1(view);
    }
}
```